# @Mapping @Mapper Error No source parameter(s) exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

I have been shifting my project from spring to Spring Boot and introducing embedded tomcat there were some adaptations i have to do Only issue i am facing in my Old project i have Mapper interface.

and when i compile project it start giving error

**Error:(12, 5) java: No property named "schoolId" exists in source parameter(s).**

I have search alot about it some said **lombok** dependency placement in pom i tried placing it before and after **map-struct** dependency but error is still here

**Following is my class**

[image]

**Following is error i am facing**

[image]

Comment: Did you remove the generated-source in the target folder? @Shermeen

Comment: @Shermeen Not sure but as per my knowledge 'target' pointed to entity and you're defining column instead of that so it gives an error. Try this, @Mapping(source = "schoolId", target="school")

Comment: @Hatice i have tried removing target folder as well but not working

Comment: @Dhwani its not working as well :(

Comment: @Shermeen Why did you put school.schoolId for target field? If this is correct, why the other target field is just schoolName instead of school.schoolName Please, change the images with code. Could you try groupDto.schoolId for source field and target just schoolId?

Comment: @Shermeen Can you share your configured code? So we cross verify it. Still i add one example in answer portion please check it.

Answer (score 9):

I think you should **re-order** the **lombok** and **mapstruct** dependencies in the pom.xml file and it works fine.

Strict ordering should be like this

1. lombok
2. mapstruct

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Shermeen Can you share your configured code?

So we cross verify it. Still i add this example please check it.

### Structure

[image]

### EntityMapper.java

```
public interface EntityMapper<D, E> {
  E toEntity(D dto);
  D toDTO(E entity);
  List<E> toEntity(List<D> dtoList);
  List<D> toDTO(List<E> entityList);
}
```

### UserMapper.java

```
import com.ecommerce.auth_service.domain.external_db.User;
import com.ecommerce.auth_service.domain.external_db.dto.UserDTO;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

import java.util.UUID;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserMapper.class})
public interface UserMapper extends EntityMapper<UserDTO, User> {

  @Mapping(source = "user_id", target = "user")

  default User fromId(UUID id) {
    if (id == null)
      return null;
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(id);
    return user;
  }
}
```

### UserMapperImpl.java

```
import com.ecommerce.auth_service.domain.external_db.User;
import com.ecommerce.auth_service.domain.external_db.dto.UserDTO;
import com.ecommerce.auth_service.domain.external_db.mapper.UserMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {
  @Override
  public User toEntity(UserDTO dto) {
    if (dto == null)
      return null;

    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(dto.getUserId());
    user.setUsername(dto.getUsername());
    user.setEmail(dto.getEmail());
    user.setPassword(dto.getPassword());
    user.setPhoneNo(dto.getPhoneNumber());
    user.setStatus(dto.getStatus());
    user.setStore(dto.getStoreId());
    user.setAuthority(dto.getAuthority());
    user.setPrivileges(dto.getAuthority().getPrivileges());

    return user;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDTO toDTO(User entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
      return null;
    }

    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();

    userDTO.setUserId(entity.getUserId());
    userDTO.setUsername(entity.getUsername());
    userDTO.setEmail(entity.getEmail());
    userDTO.setPassword(entity.getPassword());
    userDTO.setPhoneNumber(entity.getPhoneNo());
    userDTO.setStatus(entity.getStatus());
    userDTO.setStoreId(entity.getStore());

    entity.getAuthority().setPrivileges(entity.getPrivileges());
    userDTO.setAuthority(entity.getAuthority());

    userDTO.setCreatedBy(entity.getCreatedBy());
    userDTO.setCreatedDate(entity.getCreatedDate());
    userDTO.setModifiedBy(entity.getModifiedBy());
    userDTO.setModifiedDate(entity.getModifiedDate());

    return userDTO;
  }

  @Override
  public List<User> toEntity(List<UserDTO> dtoList) {
    if (dtoList == null || dtoList.isEmpty())
      return null;
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>(dtoList.size());
    for (UserDTO userDTO : dtoList) {
      userList.add(toEntity(userDTO));
    }
    return userList;
  }

  @Override
  public List<UserDTO> toDTO(List<User> entityList) {
    if (entityList == null)
      return null;
    List<UserDTO> userDTOList = new ArrayList<>(entityList.size());
    for (User user : entityList) {
      userDTOList.add(toDTO(user));
    }
    return userDTOList;
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont know how can i share my configured code on stack over flow apparently code looks fine dont know why its not recognizing source properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the most wired experience about it. in my case, I didn't declare any *annotationProcessorPaths* in my pom.xml, I just added dependencies in my pom like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

by only re-ordering it and moving up the lombok dependency the problem fixed :|

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```